# Getting error in Siebel EIM import process

Tags: siebel

SBL-EIM-00205: Failed to load the application dictionary.
SBL-SVR-01042: Internal: Communication protocol error while instantiating new task SBL-EIM-00205: Failed to load the application dictionary.

Comment: when I run the EIM process by deleting diccache.dat file, It is running successfully for one batch. for second batch again getting same errors. Everytime i have to run the process by deleting diccache.dat. Can anybody help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic message, Siebel throws it all the time there is an issue in the repository. You will have to go through the log file and get the actual error message. Increase the component log level for EIM component to maximum and re-submit the job for the logs.

The structure of the EIM tables have to match the final tables, so it could be a mismatch of schema causes this error.

Answer (score 0):

SBL-SVR-01042 this is generic error when this error is encountered while attempting to instantiate a new instance of a given component and is generic. As to why the error has occurred, one needs to review the accompanying error messages which will help provide context and more detailed information

SBL-EIM-00205: There could be many reason for this error.This is caused due to the incorrect ODBC registry entries. or some issue with Foreign key mapping.

You should increase log level and get more details.